# Помогите составить SQL запрос c JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Выведите названия продуктов, которые покупал член семьи со статусом "son". Для получения выборки вам нужно объединить таблицу Payments с таблицей FamilyMembers по полям family_member и member_id, а также с таблицей Goods по полям good и good_id.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
SELECT good_name FROM Gooods
JOIN...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT g.good_name
FROM Payments p
JOIN FamilyMembers fm ON p.family_member = fm.member_id
JOIN Goods g ON p.good = g.good_id
WHERE fm.status = 'son';
```

Верное решение